# psql: intermittent segmentation fault: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, segmentation-fault, postgis

I looked at similar-sounding questions but none seemed to address my case:

On Mac OS Siera 16GB RAM, localhost (no other postgres running anywhere)

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

The logs say:

> 2019-03-23 08:12:04.076 MDT [841] LOG:  server process (PID 1175) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
>   2019-03-23 07:13:10.459 MDT [841] LOG:  terminating any other active
>   server processes 2019-03-23 07:13:10.459 MDT [951] WARNING: 
>   terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>   2019-03-23 07:13:10.459 MDT [951] DETAIL:  The postmaster has
>   commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and
>   exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly
>   corrupted shared memory. 2019-03-23 07:13:10.459 MDT [951] HINT:  In a
>   moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your
>   command. 2019-03-23 07:13:10.460 MDT [980] FATAL:  the database system
>   is in recovery mode 2019-03-23 07:13:10.461 MDT [841] LOG:  all server
>   processes terminated; reinitializing 2019-03-23 07:13:10.470 MDT [981]
>   LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-03-23
>   07:06:47 MDT 2019-03-23 07:13:10.744 MDT [981] LOG:  database system
>   was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress 2019-03-23
>   07:13:10.746 MDT [981] LOG:  redo starts at 28/15BF74F0 2019-03-23
>   07:13:10.746 MDT [981] LOG:  invalid record length at 28/15BF7528:
>   wanted 24, got 0 2019-03-23 07:13:10.746 MDT [981] LOG:  redo done at
>   28/15BF74F0 2019-03-23 07:13:10.755 MDT [841] LOG:  database system is
>   ready to accept connections

PSQL version:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.1
```

Happens in both psql terminal and pgAdmin. No CPU or memory spikes when this happens.

It doesn't happen on simple result sets. See this example: it's the same query, the first time returning a count, the second time returning rows (which triggers the error):

```
shill=#  with yards_manual as (
 select device_id,loc, sum(sq_meters)*10.7639 as manual_yard_sq_ft from device d
    inner join zones z on (z.device_id=d.id)
    where z.enabled and z.sq_meters<46 or z.sq_meters>47 
    group by 1,2
 )

 select count(device_id) from yards_manual;
 count 
-------
 84983

shill=#  with yards_manual as (
shill(#  select device_id,loc, sum(sq_meters)*10.7639 as manual_yard_sq_ft from device d
shill(#     inner join zones z on (z.device_id=d.id)
shill(#     where z.enabled and z.sq_meters<46 or z.sq_meters>47 --and z.crop_type  in ('WARM_SEASON_GRASS','COOL_SEASON_GRASS')
shill(#     group by 1,2
shill(#  )
shill-# 
shill-#  select distinct device_id, y.manual_yard_sq_ft, build_area_ft2 , prop_area_ft2,(prop_area_ft2-build_area_ft2) as gis_yard_sq_ft2 --, st_npoints(property_geom) as corners
shill-#  from yards_manual y inner join yards b on st_contains(b.property_geom,y.loc)
shill-#  where (prop_area_ft2-build_area_ft2)>0 and (prop_area_ft2-build_area_ft2)<20000
shill-#  ;

server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

Although, this last query sometimes returns. Once it errors-out, it always errors out until I sart/stop the db. But sarting/stopping does not always work.  I have retried restarting postgres, backing up and restoring the database, to no avail. The problem just started happening. VACCUUM FULL worked fine, error still happens. The db is 24GB.

Here is the same query now randomly returning:

```
device_id | manual_yard_sq_ft |  build_area_ft2  |  prop_area_ft2   | gis_yard_sq_ft2  
----------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
 0022682e |      3999.9944068 | 1666.25757779497 |  12948.051385913 |  11281.793808118
 002a4379 |  1934.99812741536 | 2907.60847006035 |  15872.352961764 | 12964.7444917037
 002adeb4 |   1599.9984516096 | 2856.54321331877 | 9800.49184470172 | 6943.94863138295
```

But when I ran it a second time, it errored out as described above.

Here's the SQL execution plan:

```
Unique  (cost=137590686.48..137602981.21 rows=819649 width=548)
   Output: y.device_id, y.manual_yard_sq_ft, b.build_area_ft2, b.prop_area_ft2, ((b.prop_area_ft2 - b.build_area_ft2))
   CTE yards_manual
     ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=163766.01..227836.10 rows=519752 width=77)
           Output: z.device_id, d.loc, (sum(z.sq_meters) * '10.7639'::double precision)
           Group Key: z.device_id, d.loc
           ->  Gather Merge  (cost=163766.01..218090.75 rows=433126 width=77)
                 Output: z.device_id, d.loc, (PARTIAL sum(z.sq_meters))
                 Workers Planned: 2
                 ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=162765.98..167097.24 rows=216563 width=77)
                       Output: z.device_id, d.loc, PARTIAL sum(z.sq_meters)
                       Group Key: z.device_id, d.loc
                       ->  Sort  (cost=162765.98..163307.39 rows=216563 width=77)
                             Output: z.device_id, d.loc, z.sq_meters
                             Sort Key: z.device_id, d.loc
                             ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=8564.46..133948.71 rows=216563 width=77)
                                   Output: z.device_id, d.loc, z.sq_meters
                                   Hash Cond: ((z.device_id)::text = (d.id)::text)
                                   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.zones z  (cost=0.00..118450.79 rows=216563 width=45)
                                         Output: z.device_id, z.sq_meters
                                         Filter: ((z.enabled AND (z.sq_meters < '46'::double precision)) OR (z.sq_meters > '47'::double precision))
                                   ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=5648.76..5648.76 rows=120376 width=69)
                                         Output: d.loc, d.id
                                         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.device d  (cost=0.00..5648.76 rows=120376 width=69)
                                               Output: d.loc, d.id
   ->  Sort  (cost=137362850.38..137364899.50 rows=819649 width=548)
         Output: y.device_id, y.manual_yard_sq_ft, b.build_area_ft2, b.prop_area_ft2, ((b.prop_area_ft2 - b.build_area_ft2))
         Sort Key: y.device_id, y.manual_yard_sq_ft, b.build_area_ft2, b.prop_area_ft2, ((b.prop_area_ft2 - b.build_area_ft2))
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..136878917.80 rows=819649 width=548)
               Output: y.device_id, y.manual_yard_sq_ft, b.build_area_ft2, b.prop_area_ft2, (b.prop_area_ft2 - b.build_area_ft2)
               ->  CTE Scan on yards_manual y  (cost=0.00..10395.04 rows=519752 width=556)
                     Output: y.device_id, y.loc, y.manual_yard_sq_ft
               ->  Index Scan using prop_geom_idx on public.yards b  (cost=0.41..263.31 rows=2 width=173)
                     Output: b.block_id, b.property_geom, b.building_geom, b.prop_area_ft2, b.build_area_ft2, b.yard_area_ft, b.vegetation, b.yard_id
                     Index Cond: (b.property_geom ~ y.loc)
                     Filter: (((b.prop_area_ft2 - b.build_area_ft2) > '0'
```

Comment: Have you checked postgres log and maybe system log also?

Comment: @msc added logs, sorry to have omitted them.

Comment: Are you running postgres on linux? Is this possible that you have incorrect settings for memory consumption, process tries to reserve to much and is killed by OS? I haven't had such a problem, but maybe it is possible? Check also system logs and maybe monitor mem consumption during test.

Comment: Additionally PostgreSQL mailing lists may be better for such problem - https://www.postgresql.org/list/ .

Comment: @rsc missed crucial log message: segmentation fault

Comment: I really encourage you to check operating system log also. Given info you provided, it is hard to tell something more. One more thing that came to my mind, is that you could try to remove from query use of functions from postgis, maybe problem is related with this extension. Still, I would recommend you sending your problem to postgresql mailing list. This could be helpful: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/bug-reporting.html